# SQLite multiple queries faster than joins

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a question.
I have been making tests to find a way to load data from a database inside a device(tablet/smartphone). While doing those tests i found something: if i make 8 select queries as follow:

```
select table1.*,
(select count(*) from table2 where contion1) result1,
(select count(*) from table2 where contion2) result2,
(select count(*) from table3 where contion3) result3,
(select count(*) from table3 where contion4) result4,
(select table4.data1 from table4 where contion5) result5,
(select table4.data2 from table4 where contion5) result6,
(select table4.data3 from table4 where contion5) result7,
from table1 where condition6 order by table1.id
```

returns the results on an average of 10ms
and a this next query returns on an average of 25ms:

```
select table1.*, table2.result1, table2.result2, table3.result3, table3.result4, table4.data1, table4.data2,table4.data3
from(select * from table1) table1
left join( select id_table1, count(condition1) result1, count(condition2) result2
           from table2) table2 on table2.id_table1
left join( select table3.id_table1, count(condition3) result3, count(condition4) result4
           inner join table2 on table3.id_table2 = table2.id) table3 on table1.id = table3.id_table1
left join( select id_table1, data1, data2, data3 from table4) table4 on table1.id = table4.id_table1
where condition1 and condition2 and condition3 and condition4 and condition5 and condition6 order by table1.id
```

Can someone explay why this happens? As far as I know, making so many selects(specially the table4) should make it longer than the join.
I am missing something?

Note: I am dealing with a fairly large database, around the thousands rows on table2 and the hundreds on table1, so any optimizing is welcome.

Comment: You (or someone) would probably have to look at SQLite's internals (for example [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://sqlite.org/eqp.html)) to be sure. I believe there is some optimisation in place for `select count(*) from table` ... whether that kicks in when there's a `where` clause I don't know.

Comment: I have read the doc, but it still does not make sense.
It execute less instructions, and still takes more time. all the tables that I use only has a PK and not a single FK.